# Dynamical horizontal content views

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm completely new on `React` and i want to check out, if my idea is possible.

I want to create an website with following layout:

[image: Main Screen]

The green side is an collapsible navigation. On the sample screen, the navigation is showing. If an user want to hide the navigation, these will be toggled (like bootstrap navigations) with an smaller width.

The content will be stretched to the rest of complete width.

If you click on an link (depend on which link), a new view will be inserted on the left or right side on the content (see exmaples). The maximum of "Subviews" is `3`.

[image: View with one other subview]
[image]

Is these layout possible?
I want lot's of ideas and food for thought!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You want to look into flexbox and how it works in RN and also you can take a look at react-native-navigation (wix), which provides both the left and right drawer.

If you want to do it yourself, basically you want to do something like this (haven't test it):

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
<View style={{flex: 0.3, backgroundColor: "green"}}/>
<View style={{flex: 0.15, backgroundColor: "brown"}}/>
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: "silver"}}/>
<View style={{flex: 0.15, backgroundColor: "black"}}/>
</View>
```

Now, flexDirection makes the children be aligned horizontally, then the flex is basically the variable dimensions the view should cover. You can use dp or percentage here as well.

The third one has a flex of 1, meaning that it will tell RN to use as much space as possible to cover the remaining space.

In order to hide or show a particular view you can either animate them or set the style and modify the flex.

Hope it helps

Comment: Okay, react is to complex for me. I will using vanilla JS, HTML5 and CSS3. Its easier to create here an complete View/Controlling handler. React does not take any work from me, i must implement it by my self...